# Security - URLConnection Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) and File Disclosure

Tags: java

Server-Side Request Forgery occur when a web server executes a request to a user supplied destination parameter that is not validated. Such vulnerabilities could allow an attacker to access internal services or to launch attacks from your web server.

URLConnection can be used with `file://` protocol or other protocols to access local filesystem and potentially other services.

How do I fix this vulnerability?

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
URL url = new URL(pagina);
if (!url.getProtocol().startsWith("http"))
    throw new Exception();
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
if (inetAddress.isAnyLocalAddress() || inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() || inetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress()) {
    throw new Exception();
}
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
return conn;
```

Comment: The solution is to Validate it at the server. That's where the problem is. Fixing the client only fixes the problem for users at that client. Web browsers still exist, and so do other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate against the URLs passed in the requests against a set of permitted URLs in your system for making connection.

> URL url = new URL(pagina);

In your case, you can validate `url.getHost()` to check whether your system should allow requests to this system or not. A simple way to do this by creating a list of allowed URLs/addresses and then perform the validation against them.